# C# HttpGet syntax for array variable - tried {values:double[]} complains about brackets

Tags: c#, http-get

```
[HttpGet("CalibrationModelFile/{networkID:int}/{ConstituentID:int}/{values:double[]}/UpdateLimits")]
```

I have to send in an array of doubles obviously.  My function works fine if I pass in individual values like:

```
{value1: double}/{value2: double}/ etc
```

But that is pretty lame and I can have a lot of values to send.
When I try to place the call, the server gets the following error (the relevant part):
[image]

Sorry for the tiny image.

I can't find documentation anywhere that helps.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Chuck ("Yogi")

Comment: Why don't you send the values as query params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double[]` isn't one of the accepted types for constraint. The important thing to note is that these are only constraints, not true type specifiers. We can just say we want `values`, and specify in the arguments that it is a `double[]`. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints) for a list of built-in constraints.

You can do this most easily by using the `FromRoute` attribute. Specify the type in the arguments rather than the route.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("CalibrationModelFile/{networkID:int}/{ConstituentID:int}/{values}/UpdateLimits")]
public IActionResult GetThing([FromRoute(Name = "values")] double[] values)
{
      return new OkObjectResult(values);
}
```

Then call like

```
http://localhost:5000/api/CalibrationModelFile/12/13/5,2,3,4/UpdateLimits
```

Returns

```
[
  5234
]
```

Comment: thanks Josh.  This has been an obvious weak point for me, but your answer AND the html link really brings me up to speed.  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Still have the problem:
sent:
"http://localhost:60490/api/db/CalibrationModelFile/2/56/0.6938409805297852,0.6368316411972046,0.8550000190734863,0.949999988079071/UpdateLimits"

These are correct values; when creating that url, the Values parameter was a double [ , ]

Backend looks like this:
public async Task UpdateConstituentLimits(int networkID, int ConstituentID, 
            [FromRoute (Name = "values")] double[] values)
        {

Stopped in debugger: 
values = double[0];  values[0] throws exception

Any other ideas?  :-)

Comment: The same error? I've tested this on my own machine so I know this works. I'd need to see your controller code

Comment: Controller:  public async Task UpdateConstituentLimits(int networkID, int ConstituentID, 
            [FromRoute (Name = "values")] double[] values)
        {

Comment: Please edit your original answer with this information. Is it the same error?